# Which iOS LifeCycle function is better for making web requests?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift/iOS. Want to call web-service in ViewController. 
So in which method should I call the web-service between  viewwillappear and viewdidappear?

Comment: It is completely dependent of what you want to do. As name says viewwillappear will be called when view is about to show and viewdidappear is called when view is shown to the user. Also viewdidload is called once in thw lifecycle of the view where will or did appear is called whenever view appears or reappears..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call web services in `viewDidLoad`, that is called before both `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` so you will get your results sooner after your view has been presented.

I tend to use `viewDidAppear` more for starting off animation sequences etc, rather than getting data.

Answer (score 1):

its on you , it depends on  the situation. viewwillappear becomes helpful when you want to do something before view is loaded such as few settings , call of API , screen size (size of views and other designs ). 
and viewdidapear also important when you want to do some stuff after view is loaded,

Answer (score 0):

`viewWillAppear` is called before `viewDidAppear`, so i think that is better to call the web service in `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimize the Internet and/or API usage, it is better to use in `viewDidLoad:` method, because it is called only once per time the view loads (and not appears). Imagine that from this screen, you go to another, when you go back to the original screen, `viewDidLoad:` will not be called again, so you won't be using as much Internet.

If you don't want this behaviour - you want that the screen updates details each time it appears, you should use `viewWillAppear:` as it will perform a bit faster answer for the user.

More information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/).

Answer (score -1):

The best place would be to call the webservice in `viewDidLoad`. By that time you would already know which call to make and you can show a `UIActivityIndicator` to user to show some progress.